# Is it possible to determine in Cocoa whether a file was opened from an alias?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

The program I have in mind will need to be associated with all files ending with a specific extension (e.g. ".abc"), so it'll open when a user double clicks some "file.abc". Is it possible to determine in Cocoa when a user double-clicks an alias to such file?

Answer (score 1):

The application delegate will receive `application:openFile:` when launched this way. If that caused you to launch, `application:openFile:` will come between `applicationWillFinishLaunching:` and `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`. You may receive `application:openFile:` at other times, since you may already have been launched when the user double-clicks a document.

---

EDIT: Aliases are now called "bookmarks" (since 10.6). You use `NSURL` to read them. See the [File System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/AccessingFilesandDirectories/AccessingFilesandDirectories.html) for full details, but here's a short example:

```
NSURL *aliasURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"..."];
NSData *alias = [NSURL bookmarkDataWithContentsOfURL:aliasURL error:&error];
if (alias == NULL) {
  NSLog(@"Failed aliasURL: %@", error);
}

BOOL isStale;
NSURL *realURL = [NSURL URLByResolvingBookmarkData:alias options:0 relativeToURL:nil bookmarkDataIsStale:&isStale error:&error];
if (isStale || realURL == NULL) {
  NSLog(@"Failed realURL: %@", error);
}

NSLog(@"realPath:%@", [realURL path]);
```

I'm not aware of any API that will tell you if a given `NSURL` is an alias other than trying to read it as one and seeing if it fails.

Keep in mind that users might also create the same situation using symbolic links.

Comment: I meant aliases, small files which you can create using Finder's "Make Alias" context menu item.

Comment: If you wonder why I need such functionality: think of an image viewer (like Preview.app) which would scan the parent directory of the open file to preload other images — for faster browsing or to let user navigate using arrow keys. However, if you make an alias of an image and place it into other directory and then double-click it, our image viewer would scan the directory of the original image, not the directory of the alias. It would be a little counter-intuitive, and I'd like to change that in my application. Hope it makes sense and sorry for my bad grammar :X